# Haskell -- what to use for a labelled set partition?

Tags: haskell, multimap

Beginner question -- what do you usually use as a multimap? I want a function that takes a labelling function and partitions elements by each label. For example,

```
f x | x `mod` 2 == 0 = EVEN
    | otherwise = ODD
```

the output of `partition f lst` where `lst :: [Int]` would be

```
EVEN --> [list of even numbers]
ODD --> [sublist of odd numbers]
```

Sorry for the bother, I could not find something similar on Hoogle. I think I can get there via `Data.List.Key`'s `group` function, `sort`, and some mapping, but there must be a simpler way, no? This seems like a generally useful function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When there are only two cases, you can map them to booleans and use [`Data.List.partition`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v:partition).

```
Prelude Data.List> partition odd [1, 23, 42, 7, 1337, 8]
([1,23,7,1337],[42,8])
```

In the general case, you can use a [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html) with a list or set as the value type. You can build one easily using [`Data.Map.fromListWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map.html#v:fromListWith).

```
Prelude Data.Map> let partition f xs = fromListWith (++) [(f x, [x]) | x <- xs]
Prelude Data.Map> partition (`mod` 3) [1, 23, 42, 7, 1337, 8]
fromList [(0,[42]),(1,[7,1]),(2,[8,1337,23])]
```